# How to copy specific columns to a new sheet based on a user input contained within the name of a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing an audit tracking sheet for some medical coder colleagues and would like to write a macro that would allow them to easily summarize the information they are tracking. The workflow is as follows...

1. A Doctor is Selected for Audit
2. Each Patient has his/her own unique tab created that contains their specific information
3. The audit is performed in each sheet

Once the audit is complete, I need to summarize all the changes for one doctor. The naming convention of all the sheet is the same, as well as the structure.

What I would like to have happen is let them run one macro that will copy columns "R:T" from every sheet in the workbook that contains the last name of the doctor and stack them on top of one another in a new sheet. However, I want this new sheet to be created from the Macro and the name of that sheet will be a user input. I hope this is clear. Let me know if anyone needs more detail. The following code is where I have started, but I need help to get further. Please see below.

```
Sub Summary_Sheet()    
    Dim sArr() As String, Cnt As Long, WS As Object
    Dim newName As String
    ReDim sArr(0)

    newName = InputBox("Enter Doctor's Last Name")

    Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName

    Cnt = 0
    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets        
        If InStr(WS.Name, newName) Then
            ReDim Preserve sArr(Cnt)
            sArr(Cnt) = WS.Name
            Cnt = Cnt + 1
        End If        
    Next

    If Cnt > 0 Then Sheets(sArr).Select
    Set WS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Currently the code will only create a new sheet and will not select based off the new sheet name. I know that the for loop will need to copy and paste each individual sheet as opposed to selecting all of them, but I wanted to turn to the experts.

Ultimately, the columns that are copied over will need the duplicates removed and I will need to save the sheet as a pretty PDF but I need to solve this problem first. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Some screenshots will help. Anyhow, did you try to create some code or just the one on the post? I will recommend you to use the Macro Recorder for one sample, try to clean as much as you can and, then, bring the new code with your doubts. It seems that you are asking us to develop you code and SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: You don't need to create an array for this. Try to copy the columns while you are already looping through the sheets and pasting them in the new sheet you created instead of adding them to the array

Comment: Thanks for the starting point, Pablo. I have simplified the code to the following but I think it is too simple for what I am trying to capture. What do I need before calling the "copy " function. For loops and and arrays are new for me. 'Sub Summary_Sheet()

Dim WS As Object
Dim newName As String

newName = InputBox("Enter Doctor's Last Name")

Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = newName


For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

If InStr(WS.Name, "newName") Then
    Cells("C8:C8").Copy
    Sheets("Test").Range("C8").Paste

End If

Next

End Sub'

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego I did create that code through copy and paste of other sources. Do not need anything written, merely a starting point for this loop as it is my first one

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. @gbengel. With no screenshots, we don´t know how your data is disposed and which kind of data you have. You did not expose which one is your expected output.